# C# Choose from two xml files to read

Tags: c#

I want to choose from two files to read according to the comboBox19 like below:

```
           if (comboBox19.Text == "01")  XmlReader reader = new XmlReader ("C:\\Ticket Format ID01.xml");
           else if (comboBox19.Text == "02" ) XmlReader reader = new XmlReader("C:\\Ticket Format ID02.xml");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                       case:// case coding here
                     }
                }
           }
```

But there's error when I compile. The error message is "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement".
How to solve this guys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
XmlTextReader reader = null; 

if (comboBox19.Text == "01")   
    reader = new XmlTextReader ("C:\\Ticket Format ID01.xml");
else if (comboBox19.Text == "02" ) 
    reader = new XmlTextReader ("C:\\Ticket Format ID02.xml");
```

Alternatively, if your files all follow the same convention;

```
var fileName = String.Format("C:\\Ticket Format ID{0}.xml", comboBox19.Text);
var reader = new XmlTextReader (fileName);
```

Comment: I've tried both and both got this error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Xml.XmlReader'.

Comment: @Coolguy Updated to reflect, missed that one. Thanks

Comment: I edited the coding in my question. When I tried your coding an error occurred during when I call the while loop with reader.Read(). The error is: "Use of unassigned local variable 'reader'". Why is it still unassigned?

Comment: I've put in null. But when I call the while loop with reader.Read() an error occurred. The error is : Null reference exception was unhandled.

Comment: @Coolguy I suggest you add a new question as it seems you original questioned has been answered.

Comment: Problem solved when I check that the reader value is not "01" in the beginning. I've corrected it to begin with the value "01". Thanks bro!

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare reader reference variable before you use or just wrap this code around curly braces `{}` (block).

```
XmlReader reader=null;

if(comboBox19.Text == "01")
 reader =XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Ticket Format ID01.xml");
else 
if(comboBox19.Text == "02" ) 
 reader =XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Ticket Format ID02.xml");
```

Or

```
  string fileName=string.Empty;

  if(comboBox19.Text == "01")
      fileName=@"C:\Ticket Format ID01.xml";
  else 
  if(comboBox19.Text == "02" ) 
      fileName=@"C:\Ticket Format ID02.xml";

  XmlReader reader=null;
  if(!string.IsEmptyOrNull(fileName))
    {
       reader=XmlReader.Create(fileName);
    }
```

OR

```
 using(XmlReader reader=XmlReader.Create(fileName)) 
 {
  ///
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the declaration of the XmlReader outside the if-statement, and since XmlReader is an abstract class you cannot create an instance directly from it. Use `XmlTextReader` or the static method `XmlReader.Create`. You should also make the comparison to `ComboBox.SelectedValue` instead of `ComboBox.Text`:

```
XmlReader reader;
if (comboBox19.SelectedValue == "01")  
  reader = new XmlReader.Create("C:\\Ticket Format ID01.xml");
else if (comboBox19.SelectedValue == "02" )
  reader = new XmlReader.Create("C:\\Ticket Format ID02.xml");
```

Comment: I've tried this but fail also. The error message "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Xml.XmlReader'" come out.

Comment: Yes... Since XmlReader is an absctract class you cannot create an instance directly from it. Try using `XmlTextReader` or the static method `XmlReader.Create` instead.

Comment: I've edited the coding on my question because after I tried your coding with the XMLTextReader class, an error occured when I call the while loop with reader.Read(). The error is : Null reference exception was unhandled.

Comment: You need to check that the instance was properly created by checking that `reader` is not `null`. If it is then you have a problem with either the path to the XML files or that the selected value is not `01` or `02`

Comment: Problem solved when I check that the reader value is not "01" in the beginning. I've corrected it to begin with the value "01". Thanks bro!

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlReader reader = null;
if (textBox1.Text == "01")  reader = new XmlTextReader ("C:\\Ticket Format ID01.xml");
else if (textBox1.Text == "02") reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Ticket Format ID02.xml");
```

[XMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) is an **abstract** class, so you could not create an instance of it.

Comment: I've tried this but fail also. The error message "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Xml.XmlReader'" come out.

Comment: either reader = new XmlTextReader ("filename.xml") or reader = XmlReader.Create("filename.xml"); should work

Comment: I've edited the coding on my question because after I tried your coding with the XMLTextReader or XMLReader.Create an error occured when I call while loop with reader.Read(). The error is : Null reference exception was unhandled.

Comment: please share your xml as well

Comment: The problem is when I just read from one file (without if else) there's no problem. Now I'm using if else to choose a file then there's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory for the if statement to have the `{}` if we want to limit its scope to only one line. However, we cannot have a variable declaration as the only line following it. This is because if the condition results to false, the variable will never be created.

So,Declare the XMLReader before the condition. or wrap your condition code in `{}`

```
  XmlReader reader = null;
if (textBox1.Text == "01")
  reader = new XmlTextReader ("C:\\Ticket Format ID01.xml");
else if (textBox1.Text == "02")
 reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Ticket Format ID02.xml");
```

See [this link](http://www.vijaymukhi.com/documents/books/csadv/chap2.htm) for details.

Comment: I've tried this but fail also. The error message "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Xml.XmlReader'" come out.

Comment: Please see code again we get the instance of XMLReader by XMLTextReader class.Make sure you copy exact code.

Comment: I've edited the coding on my question because after I tried your coding with the XMLTextReader class an error occured when I call the while loop with reader.Read(). The error is : Null reference exception was unhandled.